# CheckBoxListTile- Space between checbox and title

Tags: flutter

What is the easiet way to do it? I want the space to be actually zero. Is it possible?

Regards

Comment: No, but you can use something like [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html#checkboxlisttile-isnt-exactly-what-i-want).

Answer (score 0):

Try playing around with `contentPadding` parameter:

```dart
CheckboxListTile(
 contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
 ...
)
```

Or you can combine the `CheckBox` with some other widget. This is going to give you something similar and you can customize the space.

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    CheckBox(...),
    Text(...),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Transform.translate`

````
Transform.translate(
      offset: const Offset(-10, 0),
      child: CheckboxListTile(
        activeColor: Colour.primary,
        controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        dense: true,
        side: const BorderSide(color: Colour.secondary50),
        value: value,
        onChanged: onChanged,
        title: Transform.translate(
          offset: const Offset(-10, 0),
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )```
````